# Why does my iframe's flexbox container have a height of 0?

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have div that contains flexbox element with iframe inside (made to be responsive using CSS).

In Firefox that parent's height is 0 for some reason.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px black solid;
}
.flexbox {
  max-width: 854px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow
}
.flexbox div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
flexbox div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="flexbox">
<div>
<span>
  TExT
</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The best way to see this please look at my example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5jLqugy6/

Comment: What iframe? Your code doesn't include one.

Comment: Because percentage padding fails in a flex container in FF and Edge. However, the spec has recently been updated, so your code may work in upcoming versions. See the duplicate for full details.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that other, barely-related CSS question? I would like an answer to this question. @Michael_B why did you mark this as duplicate?

Comment: If you take the time to read the answers in the duplicate, you'll see why. @AndrewKoster

Comment: Both problems are caused by browsers interpreting CSS sizing specs in ways that make (for practical purposes) no sense. If I wanted a box to have a height of zero, I would give it one of these heights: "0", "0px", or "0%". It's really weird that the default behavior of browsers is, in some cases, to convert a nonzero number to zero.

Comment: Still don't see how the two problems are the exact same problem, though. It's confusing to lump them together.

Answer (score -1):

I believe its because you have not set the height of the parent container or the child element within the parent.